# What does [nopass] mean in the dictionary?

Tags: meaning

> afford
>
> 1. [nopass]to have enough money or time to be able to buy or to do sth
> 2. [nopass]~ **to do sth** if you say that youcan't afford to do sth, you mean that you should not do it because it will cause problems for you
>      if you do

What does the `[nopass]` mean in the dictionary's explanation?

Comment: I don't know of any dictionary that would use those definitions—especially the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.. It seems that it means `[no passive]`. I am using a bad dictionary.